# Getting inner text of dynamically generated id element to send to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, google-analytics

I am logging click events on my website to Google Analytics. The way I do on buttons clicked is this:

```
document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener("click", function() { 
    ga('send', 'event', 'Login Button', 'clicked'); 
}, false);
```

I also would like to log the tabs clicked on a FAQ I have on a `<p:accordionPanel>` element, from PrimeFaces. Code follows:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="helpAccordion" value="#{indexFAQController.helperBean}" var="bean" multiple="false" >
   <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{indexFAQController.onTabChange}" />
   <p:tab id="helpTab" title="#{bean.title}">
      #{bean.message}
   </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

The way the ids are generated on the view is dynamic. Every accordion tab is composed of a `<h3>` and a `<div>` with the dynamic ID of **helpAccordion:n:helpTab**, where **n** is the auto-generated tab number, starting from **0**. Code:

```
<div id="helpAccordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container" role="tablist" data-widget="widget_helpAccordion">
   <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>TAB TITLE 0</h3>
   <div id="helpAccordion:0:helpTab" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
      TAB TEXT 0.
   </div>
   <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>TAB TITLE 1</h3>
   <div id="helpAccordion:1:helpTab" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-helper-hidden" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
      TAB TEXT 1.
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="helpAccordion_active" name="helpAccordion_active" value="0" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

So I need a way to get which tab was clicked and get the beginning inner text of it (if possible, the title in the corresponding `<h3>` would be even better) of it for it to be passed to the Google Analytics function.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have one listener at the top of the page (body).  The listener gets the event, and is able to figure out what element originated the click-event.  Maybe you would have some specific data-attribute on each element that you care about.

For example:

`<p:accordionPanel data-send-to-google="whatever">Accordion panel!</p>`

`function theHandler(ev) {
   if (ev.target.hasAttribute("data-send-to-google")) {
     const theData = ev.target.getAttribute("data-send-to-google");
     ga('send', 'event', theData, 'clicked'); 
   }
 }
 document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", theHandler);`

Comment: This reduced the number of listeners I have on my code, but it did not get the clicks on the tabs of the accordion. While debugging it, the target does not have the data-send-to-google attribute, despite its presence on both `<p:accordionPanel>` and `<p:tab>`.

Comment: I suspect there may be some (dynamic) element inside the paragraphs that's receiving the clicks.  Browser Developer Tools can, of course, help to confirm that.  The click handler may need to walk up the hierarchy with el.parentNode until it finds the attribute.